# Dar un ancho especifico a un borde

Tags: css3

Quiero dar hacer un borde con un tamaño en especifico en un `div` pero no logro como hacerlo, porque si coloco `border-top: 1px solid #000;` el borde estaria abarcando todo el tamaño del contendor y yo quiero es colocarlo a la mitad o a mi gusto.

```
<div>
```

```css
.contenedor{
width:100px;
border-top: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
<h2> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: No acabo de entender la pregunta, el borde con el tamaño en específico te refieres al tamaño del grosor del borde o al tamaño del borde en el div?

Comment: Me refiero a la longitud del borde, que si yo tengo un container de 400 de largo yo pueda colocar un borde encima que solo ocupe la mitad del container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un elemento "after", fijate que entre el primer y el segundo ejemplo cambia el model box del div (al agregar un borde al 2 se respetan los márgenes del H1 y el P respecto al DIV), entre el 3 y el 4 hay un BR para separar. A 3, 4 y 5 se les aplica un borde transparente al DIV.

```css
.contenedor{
  width: 400px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.contenedor.bordealamitad::after{
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  content:" ";
}
.masancho {
 width: 600px;
}
.borderesaltado {
border: 1px dashed red;
}
.bordetransparente {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor bordealamitad">
<h2>1 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem</p>
</div>
<div class="contenedor bordealamitad masancho borderesaltado">
<h2>2 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLoremLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem</p>
</div>
<div class="contenedor bordealamitad masancho bordetransparente">
<h2>3 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem</p>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="contenedor bordealamitad bordetransparente">
<h2>4 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem  </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLoremLorem ipsum </p>
</div>
<div class="contenedor bordealamitad masancho bordetransparente">
<h2>5 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem  </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría dos divs, uno con el ancho máximo, pongamos por ejemplo, 400px; y uno más pequeño, por ejemplo de 200px.

Entonces al div pequeño le pones la propiedad `border-top` y listo.